# How to clean up my Excel File (CSV, XLSX, ...) Database in PHP in my case?

Tags: php

I have three different (3) **Excel** files (in `.xlsx`, `.csv` format) whose Header containing the `Email` column is placed in different positions (sometimes in the 2nd place, sometimes in 5th or even 7th place) on each of the files.

Knowing that the two pieces of code that I am trying to use to delete all the rows whose Emails columns are not valid are the following:

```
// Validate Emails with PHP Coding:
if (filter_var($email_address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false || preg_match('/@.+\./', $email_address) === false) {
    // email is not valid syntax
}


// Check Email Domain MX Record with PHP (capture domain extension): 
$email_host = strtolower(substr(strrchr($email_address, "@"), 1));
// set host to fully qualified domain:
$email_host = idn_to_ascii($email_host.'.');
if (!checkdnsrr($email_host, "MX")) {
    // email invalid -> domain does not have a valid MX record
}
```

Can you help me combine the two codes above which checks the validity of Email Server Names in order to clean (*by deleting all the rows whose Emails columns are not valid*) my database (*knowing how all Excel databases do not have header level , the Email column at the same position*) ???

Thanks to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to move that logic to a function?

```php
function isEmailValid(string $email_address): bool
{
    // Validate Emails with PHP Coding:
    if (filter_var($email_address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false || preg_match('/@.+\./', $email_address) === false) {
        return false;
    }


    // Check Email Domain MX Record with PHP (capture domain extension): 
    $email_host = strtolower(substr(strrchr($email_address, "@"), 1));
    // set host to fully qualified domain:
    $email_host = idn_to_ascii($email_host.'.');
    if (!checkdnsrr($email_host, "MX")) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Note, I didn't inspect any of your actual logic for email validation, I just wrapped it.